# how to effectively troubleshoot why a raspberry pi is shutting down

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi 3 B+, and am using the official raspberry pi power supply along with a Logitech C270 HD webcam.
I am attempting to stream video from this camera to a browser. I have done this successfully, but my raspberry pi keeps rebooting after about 10 seconds of streaming video.
Can anyone provide some guidance on how one would troubleshoot an issue like this?
What I have done so far:

1. When I start streaming video I am using the raspian task manager to
   view ram and cpu usage. It is sitting at about 55% CPU usage, and
   208MB out of 926MB used.
2. I am also using a current meter to check the current draw on the power supply to the raspberry pi and it peaks at about 820 mA when the pi reboots.

Are there any specific logs I could view?

Additional context:
I am using django to run the local server to serve the video stream. The video stream is being generated from open cv. And finally, I am using ngrok to provide an https tunnel so that I can access the django server externally.

Comment: IMO it shouldn't reboot, it's possible that the CPU overheats. Is it hot?

Comment: And also look for *Undervoltage* logs in `dmesg`

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` to see the end of the logs of the previous boot. Or look at `/var/log/*log`.

Comment: Hmm yeah no smoking guns anywhere there. It is not getting overly hot, but I don't know how hot it should be. I'll get my IR temp gun and take some measurements.

Comment: I just tried to run it headless using SSH, and it still reboots after about 15 seconds or so of streaming video.

Comment: Do you connect your camera through USB? Could you try using a powered USB hub?

Comment: Yes the camera is powered through the raspberry pi USB ports. I don't own a powered USB hub, but maybe I can track one down to do some testing.